# Alert input form

Tags: javascript, forms, jsp

I want to make an alert for form input caharcter that depends on the datatype,

when I type the wrong input, the alert is showed like this
[image]

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function check_field(id) {
        var field = document.getElementById(id);
        var d = document.getElementById('plus');
        if (isNaN(field.value)) {
            d.innerHTML += "Is not number";
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="t_field" onchange="check_field('t_field');"/><b id='plus'></b><br>
    <input type="text"/>
</form>
</body>
```

When I try to delete the input character the alert is still showed, I want the alert change to another alert otherwise it dissapear from the screen.

the problem above is solved but there is one problem anymore

[loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fWiY.png)

do you understand what i mean?

Comment: Please look at my answer. There is a concatenation of the is not number because you use `+=` use `=` instead as in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `else` block to handle when it is a right input.

```
if (isNaN(field.value)) 
{
  d.innerHTML = "Is not number";
}
else
{
  d.innerHTML = "";
}
```

```html
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function check_field(id) {
        var field = document.getElementById(id);
        var d = document.getElementById('plus');
        if (isNaN(field.value)) {
            d.innerHTML = "Is not number";
        }
      else
        {
            d.innerHTML = "";
          }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="t_field" onchange="check_field('t_field');"/><b id='plus'></b>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function check_field(id) {
        var field = document.getElementById(id);
        var d = document.getElementById('plus');
        if (isNaN(field.value)) {
            d.innerHTML = "Is not number";
        } else {
          d.innerHTML = "";
        }
    }
```

```html
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="t_field" onkeyup="check_field('t_field');"/><b id='plus'></b><br>
    <input type="text"/>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please minimise your code like below

```
 <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function check_field(id) {
                var d = document.getElementById('plus');
                if (isNaN(id.value)) {
                    d.innerHTML = "Is not number";
                }
               else
               {
                  d.innerHTML = "";
               }
            }
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="t_field" onchange="check_field(this);"/><b id='plus'></b><br>
            <input type="text"/>
        </form>
        </body>
```